# Failed : HTTP error code : 400 While postin JSON data to URL

Tags: java, json

I tried searching the net for this issue but finally ended up getting no proper answer.

I am trying to post a json data to a URL, I have no idea where my code went wrong, I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400`
It would be of great help if anyone could help me outwith this issue.

**MyCode :**

```
public class JsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://10.48.151.32:30304/transactionManagement/v2/transaction");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

         }

        }

    }
```

**Error Exception :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
    at JsonTest.main(JsonTest.java:36)
```

**My JSON DATA:**

```
{
"request": {
"header": {
"signature": "BHNUMS",
"details": {
"productCategoryCode": "01",
"specVersion": "04"
}
},
"transaction": {
"primaryAccountNumber": "8961060000402122658",
"processingCode": "725400",
"transactionAmount": "000000000200",
"transmissionDateTime": "150505141718",
"systemTraceAuditNumber": "035689",
"localTransactionTime": "141718",
"localTransactionDate": "150505",
"merchantCategoryCode": "0443",
"pointOfServiceEntryMode": "021",
"pointOfServiceConditionCode":"00",
"transactionFeeAmount":"000000000200",
"acquiringInstitutionIdentifier": "10998156762",
"track2Data":";8961060000402122658=4912?",
"retrievalReferenceNumber": "44436440441",
"merchantTerminalId": "87654     987   ",
"merchantIdentifier": "10998156762",
"merchantLocation": "688 PACIFIC HIGHWAYYY CHHHHATSWOOD NSWAU",
"transactionCurrencyCode": "840",
"additionalTxnFields": 
{ "productId": "07675018955" ,
   "externalAccountNumber":"353142040651369",
   }
}
}
}
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: 404 means the URL doesn't exist on the server. Check your url again.

Comment: 400 is "bad request". Some expected parameters or headers are not present. Are you sure about the Content Type header you're sending? Do you have the docs for the web service you're calling or sample requests?

Comment: `{"error":{"message":"No operation is found at URI: /rest/transactionManagement/v2/transaction HTTP Method:GET","type":"com.bea.wlcp.wlng.rest.ResourceNotFoundException"}}` I get this when I run the url in my browser.

Comment: But things work fine when I use postman application

Comment: @suganthikanagaraj you should have a `POST` method to post something at this api `/rest/transactionManagement/v2/transaction` not a `GET` method. In postman you must be using `POST`

Comment: Yes, your browser sends a GET request while the end point expects a POST. Can you capture what the working application sends?

Comment: When I pushed the data through poster application it was working fine, I have added screenshot

Comment: What was sent in the Postman (or the other application you used) request body? Can you post it here?

Comment: @Eldius : Poster applciations Body is nothing but my JSOn data which I have posted in my question above.

Comment: @Eldius I have also attached a screenshot of poster application with body content and response pls take that also as a reference!

Comment: Can you try to set conn.setDoInput(true) to test?

Comment: yes I tried now, Still I am getting the same error :(

Comment: One other thing... Can you post the response message? It may bring some light in this problem...

Comment: Response message while using Poster Application I have attached in the screenshot, response while running through java code is nothing but the exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400
    at JsonTest.main(JsonTest.java:36)`

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this error .You need to add extra line in your code

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0.2 Waterfox/27.0");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

conn.setDoInput(true);

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
```

conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");